# Can we go back and execute the if condition after executing the else condition by just changing the if condition?

Tags: c

I had the following question for my C exam:

What should you write in place of 'condition' to print the statement 'I love food' in just one execution? You cannot add any more code.

```
    if(condition)
    printf("food");
    else
    printf("I love");
```

Comment: `if (printf("I love ")) printf("food");`

Comment: @mch Great answer, simple and clean code!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not quite, the (admittedly stupid) exam question asks to replace `condition` and nothing else.

Comment: @Jabberwocky aaah I see your point now.

Comment: @mch make that an answer.

Comment: Is this a question for an exam "how to program the worst way possible"?

Comment: Is that all the code you get in the question?

Comment: Please inform your instructor that approximately the entire internet thinks this is a bad exam question and they should feel bad for having asked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change `condition` to `printf("I love ")`. `printf` returns the number of printed characters, which will be 7, so the condition is true.

```
if (printf("I love "))
    printf("food");
else
   printf("I love");
```

Comment: nice, that kind of programming is discouraged. Can be useful when you cannot change the code directly, but only with macros.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Whoever asks such exam questions should be forced to teach whitespace instead (with a whiteboard/paper handouts to students only). Provided there is no additional code which makes this at least a bit more reasonable. Note there **has to be** more, because the snippet in the question is apparently no valid C program.

Comment: it's true that there are a million more interesting things to ask at an exam. Smartass teachers...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: _Smart_a**?? Definitively only the second part.